# make a mysql query after click in a row of Jquery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to do a master-detail table using JQuery Datatables. I have a table **facture** and a table **lines**. The table **facture** has got a code for PK, and the client name. In the table *lines** I have got the code of the facture, the number of the line, the article and the price. I want to click in one row of the table **facture** and it may show the lines for this facture in the table **lines**.
I'm sorry if I'm not explaining well. If you don't understand what I'm tying to do I'll try to explain better.
Now I have this code for show all the **line** table.

**js function for show the query in a div**

```
function objetoAjax(){
            var xmlhttp=false;
          try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
              }
          }

        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function MostrarConsulta(datos){
        divResultado = document.getElementById('mus');
        ajax=objetoAjax();
        ajax.open("GET", datos);
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (ajax.readyState==4) {
                divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
            }
        }
        ajax.send(null)
    }
```

**php code for the query**

```
include"conexion.php";
mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave)or die (mysql_errno().mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($basedatos)or die (mysql_errno().mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query("SELECT Serie, Numeroas, Numlinea, Codart, Cant, Descripcion, Precio, Tipoiva, Subtotal FROM PRESUP_D");
echo "<table border=1 collapse=\"collapse\" bgcolor=\"white\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    while($field=mysql_fetch_field($result)){   
        echo"<td><b>$field->name</b></td>"; 
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){   
        echo "<tr>";
        for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_fields($result);$i++){    
            echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";   
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
```

I call the function with a form with an event onsubmit="MostrarConsulta('linea.php'); return false.
It show all the table and I want to get the value of the selected row in table **facture** and do this query with that.

Regards.

Comment: Showing some representative code might be helpful

Comment: I edit the post and add the code that I'm using now.